# Migrating from lucene 2.x to 3.x

Tags: lucene

I am porting my app from lucene 2.X to lucene 3.X. The following is my issue.

This one was valid in 2.X, but 3.5 throws me an error.

`IndexReader reader = IndexReader.open("/home/path/to/my/dataDir");`

2.X accepted a string, but 3.5 strictly wants a Directory object. I find Directory to be abstract and the only way to instantiate it seems a RAMDirectory().

How do I go about this and how do I point my reader to the desired directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use 
`DirectoryReader.open(FSDirectory
                .open(new File(indexFilePath)))`
as IndexReader.open method is deprecated for lucene 4 :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it. I just did it this way

```
IndexReader reader = IndexReader.open(new SimpleFSDirectory(new File("my/desired/path")));`
```

Thanks for your time.